# How to use slice to get the biggest values just from a variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, slice

I'm having serious problems by using the function **dplyr :: slice()**.

I need to create with **mutate()** a new variable that shows the biggest values just for a variable and an observation. Specifically, I need to show the winner party in an election in each town, but I always get the biggest winner of all the dataframe instead of the winner of each town.

My teacher has told me to use: slice_max(my_variable, n = 1). But I need to link it with another variable. Any ideas?

```
votos_cyl %>% 
  filter(prov %in% c("Ãvila")) %>%
  mutate(winner = slice_max(votos_partido_pc, n = 1)) %>%
  distinct(mun, .keep_all= TRUE) %>% 
  select(mun, part, ganador) %>% 
  arrange(desc(part)) %>% 
  slice_max(part, n=10)
```

When I code this, it shows error due to numeric variable.
Before, I used function max() but the result was the biggest observation of my df as I said before

Comment: I think you are missing `group_by` somewhere.

Comment: Exactly, I needed to group_by(town)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

`slice_max()` is meant for dataframes, not vectors (which is what you are supplying it inside `mutate()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Slice max works with dataframes
mtcars %>% 
  slice_max(hp)
#>               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#> Maserati Bora  15   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8

# But gives error inside mutate
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    x = slice_max(hp)
  )
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `x = slice_max(hp)`.
#> Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
#> ! no applicable method for 'slice_max' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

#### Solution

In your case, you can use `which.max()` to get the party with the most votes:

```r
# Let's pretend this is your data
df <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("party") %>% 
  select(
    party,
    town = cyl,
    votes = hp
  ) %>% 
  head()

df
#>               party town votes
#> 1         Mazda RX4    6   110
#> 2     Mazda RX4 Wag    6   110
#> 3        Datsun 710    4    93
#> 4    Hornet 4 Drive    6   110
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout    8   175
#> 6           Valiant    6   105

# To get the party with the most votes, you can use which.max()
df %>% 
  group_by(town) %>% 
  mutate(
    winner = party[which.max(votes)]
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   town [3]
#>   party              town votes winner           
#>   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            
#> 1 Mazda RX4             6   110 Mazda RX4        
#> 2 Mazda RX4 Wag         6   110 Mazda RX4        
#> 3 Datsun 710            4    93 Datsun 710       
#> 4 Hornet 4 Drive        6   110 Mazda RX4        
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout     8   175 Hornet Sportabout
#> 6 Valiant               6   105 Mazda RX4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This worked more or less. I got what I want (winner party in a town) but now I don't have the order I want as the conditions I wrote in arrange. Is it because an order argument?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. Do you want `winner` to be the name of the party with the most votes, or do you want it to be the number of votes?

Comment: The name of the party with most votes

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer. I think this should solve your problems. Next time you post a question it's a good idea to include some data and a description of what you would like your output to look like :)

Comment: The votes and the name of the party were different variables, but it worked anyway. Thx for your help :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If my answer solved your problem, please "accept" my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of my answer (under the arrows). You can read more about what accepting an answer means [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).